# Rename the folder dynamically in Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

how to rename folders when transferring from one container to anther container by using  dynamically in azure data factory

I want to modify the folder name by dynamically

Comment: Provide the sample data and desired results

Answer (score 0):

I tried to dynamically rename the folder in ADF pipeline while copying. Below is the process.

- Lookup activity is taken with the dataset containing old_name and new_name of the folder.
  [image]
- In For-each, Copy data is taken. In source dataset, folder name is given dynamically.
  **Wildcard File Path:** container2/`@{item().old_name}`/*
  [image]
- In sink dataset, new folder name is given dynamically in another container.
  **File Path:** container1/`@{item().new_name}`/
  [image]
- Files are copied to new container with new folder names.